# Search part of a string in a record with multiple strings

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have the following record in `artists` table:

```
| id | names                |

| 1  | eminem rihanna rita ora|
| 2  | taylor swift beyonce   |
```

I want to search for example using `inem` and I want the `id` of this record to be found which is `id = 1` in this case. I'm using `Full Text Search in MySQL`.

Is there a better technique to achieve this?

Update:

```
 | id | video_name | title  | artists | search_tags       | 
 | 1  | onajr      | o'najr | kida    | onajr o'najr kida |
```

I want to search using this strings for ex. `onajr, ona, kida, kid`.
So in e few words a user can search using al the search tags including part of a tag.

This is my function in php. :

```
public function tags_search() {
        //echo 'ok';
        $db = DB::get_instance();
            //single word

            $query = "
            select * from `videos` 
            where 
                match(`search_tags`) against (':video_name' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by rand()
            limit 1
            ";
            try {
            $run_query = $db->prepare($query);
            $run_query->execute(array(
                ':string' => $this->string
            ));

            return ($run_query->rowCount() == 1) ? $run_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->video_name : false;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better than what? Show us the code you fear may be suboptimal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use `LIKE`

```
SELECT id FROM artists WHERE names LIKE '%inem%';
```

The `%`'s are wild cards saying that anything can come before or after them.

Also, it's generally not a good idea to store multiple values in a single field. I'd recommend making `id` and `names` into a composite PK, and then only have one name per field.

eg)

```
| id | name         |

| 1  | eminem       |
| 1  | rihanna      |
| 1  | rita ora     |
| 2  | taylor swift |
| 2  | beyonce      |
```

If you plan on adding more fields, they should be in another table. Learn about [database normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) for the reason why.

**Edit after update:**

I still think a `LIKE` statement would suit your purposes, the only thing you would have to do different is add a `AND search_tags LIKE '%ona%'` etc for each comma delineated tag word.

Just as an example from what you have above:

```
SELECT id FROM artist 
WHERE search_tags LIKE '%onajr%'
    AND search_tags LIKE '%ona%'
    AND search_tags LIKE '%kida%'
    AND search_tags LIKE '%kid%';
```

I don't know enough about PHP to actually give you some code, but after a short search, [explode()](http://php.net/explode) appears to be the function you want to look at. Then just append the extra SQL for each search tag. This method would also work if you were to split your tags into another table. If I'm not mistaken, you should just have to group by the songid if you go that route.

Not sure if all this is better than what you have. As I said, I don't know much PHP, and I haven't messed around with `match(...) against(...)`, but I thought I'd throw in my own 2¢.

Comment: I need to have them in a single field because all the strings define one single song and an artist can sing more than one song so there will be many dublicate rows with the same tags.

Comment: I think looking at DB normalization would be good. From what I see, you would need one table with the song and an ID and any info specific to the song, another with your individual tags and the appropriate songID (looking a bit like the above), and a third with an artist and songID (again, like above). Perhaps you might see it as more work, but I think it may save time in the long run (plus I like doing things the "right way" whatever that means).